# Flutter, how do I correctly declare and use variables in a stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I have a `StatefulWidget` that contains a `ListView()` with a `ListView.builder()`. The `ListView.builder()` builds several `CheckboxListTile()`'s using two Lists, one for the labels and one for the booleans. However it is not working as intended. I tried to create a minimal example of the problem, it looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestClassState createState() => _TestClassState();
}

class _TestClassState extends State<TestClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool firstBoolean = false;
    bool secondBoolean = false;
    List labels = [
    "First Checkbox",
    "Second Checkbox",
    ];  
    List<bool> booleans = [
      firstBoolean,
      secondBoolean,
    ];    
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          child: ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("${labels[index]}"),
                  value: booleans[index],
                  onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      secondBoolean = newValue;
                      print(
                          "firstBoolean, secondBoolean: [$firstBoolean, $secondBoolean]");
                    });
                  },
                );
              }),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

This does not change the checkboxes and also not the assigned booleans. If I replace this line:

```
value: booleans[index]
```

with

```
value: firstBoolean
```

And move the `bool firstBoolean = false;` above the `@override` in the `_TestCassState` It 'works' but since all the checkboxes now have the same boolean variable assigned to them it changes all of them at the same time. But I dont understand why this 'works' and the code above does not. Also if I try to create all the booleans I need above `@override` and then try to create a list containing all of them, I get this error:

> The instance member 'firstBoolean' can't be accessed in an
> initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a
> different expression

If I move to List with the labels above the `@override` it doesnt give me this error and assigns the labels correctly

I feel like I am not understanding something fundamental about StatefulWidgets. So I would really aprecciate if somebody could give me an explanation of how to solve this correctly and why this is not working as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need the individual bool variables.

You can basically have your `labels` inside your `TestClass` since they are not part of the state since they never change.

Next, you can have just the `List<bool> booleans` in your `State` class since all your changing stuff is just these `booleans` itself.

So your structure will be like this now.

```
class TestClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final List labels = [
    "First Checkbox",
    "Second Checkbox",
  ];
  
  @override
  _TestClassState createState() => _TestClassState();
}
```

This is good practice to put them in the `StatefulWidget` class. You can then use them inside your `State` class like this - `widget.labels[index]`.

So, your `State` class will be,

```
class _TestClassState extends State<TestClass> {
  List<bool> booleans = [false,false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text("${widget.labels[index]}"),
                value: booleans[index],
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    // There was a logic error here in your code, so changed it to work correctly
                    booleans[index] = newValue;
                });
              },
            );
          }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when ever you call a `setstate()` then the build method is invoked, and you are declared in the build method.

override the `initState()` method of state.

```
class _TestClassState extends State<TestClass> {
   bool firstBoolean,secondBoolean;
   List labels;
   List<bool> booleans;
  
  @override
   void initState(){
    super.initState();
       firstBoolean = false;
     secondBoolean = false;
     labels = [
    "First Checkbox",
    "Second Checkbox",
    ];  
    booleans = [
      firstBoolean,
      secondBoolean,
    ];    
  }
}
```

and remove the variable declarations from build method

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call the setState() method the build function gets called and initialises the variables with the same old value .
The simplest solution to your problem is to keep the variables out of build function so that they don't get initialised everytime you call setState() method .
Here's what you should do

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class TestClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestClassState createState() => _TestClassState();
}

class _TestClassState extends State<TestClass> {
    // Declare the variables above build fucntion
    bool firstBoolean = false; 
    bool secondBoolean = false;
    List labels = [
    "First Checkbox",
    "Second Checkbox",
    ];  
    List<bool> booleans = [false,false];    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          child: ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("${labels[index]}"),
                  value: booleans[index],
                  onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      secondBoolean = newValue;
                      print(
                          "firstBoolean, secondBoolean: [$firstBoolean, $secondBoolean]");
                    });
                  },
                );
              }),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variables in the wrong place, you have initialised those inside the build function. So whenever you call setState the variable will be re-initialised to the default values. Also you don't need to use `firstBoolean` and `secondBoolean`. Change your code to:

```dart
class TestClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestClassState createState() => _TestClassState();
}

class _TestClassState extends State<TestClass> {

  List labels = [
    "First Checkbox",
    "Second Checkbox",
  ];
  List<bool> booleans = List.filled(2, false); // Initialising with default value

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text("${labels[index]}"),
                value: booleans[index],
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    booleans[index] = newValue;
                    print(booleans[index]);
                  });
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```